# WKInterfaceButton not clicking - Xcode 7 & Watch simulator

Tags: button, watchkit, xcode7, watchos-2

I updated to Xcode 7 and my button in my Apple watch extension is not working anymore. I already checked and the button is enabled and the action is linked.
The button is in Interface.storyboard.
I'm on watch simulator.

Is someone else having this same issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7.0 or 7.1 (beta)?